# can't include flash in drupal..flash doesn't appears

Tags: php, html, flash, drupal

I have downloaded a flash component "Fade In Fade Out Slideshow".and included my images in it. I don't know how to include it in drupal
its index.html page is

```
<html xmlns="http`enter code here`://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<title>XML Banner Rotator</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    </head>
<body>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/swfobject.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">

            // JAVASCRIPT VARS
            // cache buster
            var cacheBuster = "?t=" + Date.parse(new Date());
            // stage dimensions     
            var stageW = "560";//"100%";
            var stageH = "374";//"100%";


            // ATTRIBUTES
            var attributes = {};
            attributes.id = 'FlabellComponent';
            attributes.name = 'FlabellComponent';

            // PARAMS
            var params = {};
            params.bgcolor = "#ffffff";
            params.menu = "false";
            params.scale = 'noScale';
            params.wmode = "opaque";
            params.allowfullscreen = "true";
            params.allowScriptAccess = "always";            


            /* FLASH VARS */
            var flashvars = {};

            /// if commented / delete these lines, the component will take the stage dimensions defined 
            /// above in "JAVASCRIPT SECTIONS" section or those defined in the settings xml
            flashvars.componentWidth = stageW;
            flashvars.componentHeight = stageH;

            /// path to the content folder(where the xml files, images or video are nested)
            /// if you want to use absolute paths(like "http://domain.com/images/....") then leave it empty("")         
            flashvars.pathToFiles = "banner/";

            // path to content XML
            flashvars.xmlPath = "xml/banner.xml";


            /** EMBED THE SWF**/
            swfobject.embedSWF("preview.swf"+cacheBuster, attributes.id, stageW, stageH, "9.0.124", "js/expressInstall.swf", flashvars, params, attributes);

        </script>

        <table width="100%" height="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <td align="center">

                <!-- this div will be overwritten by SWF object -->     
                <div id="FlabellComponent">
                    <p>In order to view this object you need Flash Player 9+ support!</p>
                    <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer">
                        <img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player"/>
                    </a>
                </div>

            </td>
        </table>        

    </body>

</html>
```

i have downloaded a flash component "Fade In Fade Out Slideshow".and included mu images in it.i don't know how to include it in drupal
any idea????

i tried to embed its preview.swf using the below code..but flash image doesn't displays.

```
<div id="swfhead">
<object height="205" width="950">
<param value="preview.swf" name="movie">
<embed height="205" width="950" src="preview.swf">
</object>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You cant embed swf as you did. Please refer theme concepts in drupal.org

Bio : http://drupal.org/user/1313260